# ОС для детей

Tags: ос

Кто может посоветовать операционную систему для ребенка? Нашел [Qimo 4 Kids](http://www.qimo4kids.com/download/), но может кто-то знает какие-нибудь сборки поинтереснее?

Answer (score 2):

Есть ещё [DoudouLinux](http://www.doudoulinux.org), однако мне больше понравилась Qimo, чего-то лучше так и не смог найти...

Comment: Чем больше понравилась? Что лучше, что хуже?

Comment: QIMO больше понравилась тем,что это по сути обычный дистрибутив дебиан,просто с парочкой предустановленных для детей пакетов и соответствующим оформлением)То есть ребенок действительно учится основам работы с компютером и в частности с операционной системой.Дудулинукс же,по крайней мере когда она попалась мне(больше года назад),походит на сборник игрушек,рисовалок и пр.,что-то на подобие детских компьютеров продающихся в игрушечных магазинах,для детей лет 2-5 наверное сойдёт)))

Comment: Моему как раз 3...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [Top 6 Linux Distributions for Children (Ages 2 and Up)](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/43224.aspx), может найдете альтернативу или что-то подходящее.

Answer (score 1):

А что вкладывается в понятие "ОС для ребенка"? Если нужен дистрибутив, толерантный к необдуманным действиям - то монтируем / в read-only и /home при загрузке копируем со ссылкой в темп - в итоге при каждой загрузке возвращаемся к предустановленному состоянию но даём возможность на время сеанса менять /home

Если нужен дистрибутив, с максимальным набором edu-продуктов ... то вообщем-то в любом настольном дистрибутиве этот набор примерно одинаковый, его только нужно установить т.к. по умолчанию edu обычно не ставится - на серверах он не нужен ;-)
Для дебиана/убунты: **apt-cache search education**

В убунте соотв. найдутся:

- ubuntu-edu-preschool - Preschool Educational Application Bundle
- ubuntu-edu-primary - Primary Educational Application Bundle
- ubuntu-edu-secondary - Secondary Educational Application Bundle
- ubuntu-edu-tertiary - Tertiary Educational Application Bundle

Для постарше в той-же убунте или дебиане найдутся например:

- science-astronomy - Debian Science Astronomy packages
- science-chemistry - Debian Science Chemistry packages
- science-electronics - Debian Science Electronics packages
- science-geography - Debian Science Geography packages
- science-geometry - Debian Science geometry packages
- science-highenergy-physics - Debian Science High Energy Physics
  packages
- science-highenergy-physics-dev - Debian Science High Energy Physics
  development packages
- science-mathematics - Debian Science Mathematics packages
- science-nanoscale-physics - Debian Science Nanoscale Physics packages
- science-nanoscale-physics-dev - Debian Science Nanoscale Physics
  development packages
- science-physics - Debian Science Physics packages

Это по большей части справочники и утилиты (в том числе и вполне пригодные для серьезой работы) но если ребенок увлечен например астрономией, то в астро-пакете есть и справочники (правда бОльшую часть надо выкачивать руками т.к. они весьма объемные) и утилитки для контроля телескопов (подвижек) и для проявки равок с пзс матриц - вообщем полный набор как для начинающего так и для вполне себе астронома :-)